# How do I remove this sliding drawer in my kitchen?

Tags: kitchens, drawers

OK, so I for the life of me can not figure out how to take these drawers off of their slides.  The ones I have used in the past have had obvious tabs to push in, or you just had to lift the drawer up or down in the extended position to have them disengage from the slide.

If anyone has used the specific kinds before or if you have not and think I have just lost my marbles please let me know :)

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Comment: Some of them with an undertrack like that will come out if you just tug on it a little harder than usual. I'm NOT saying ALL of them are made that way, but all the ones I've dealt with have been.

Comment: have you tried lifting it a bit at the end of the track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of slide decouples simply by giving the drawer a good tug in the straightout direction. It is advised to start the tug when the drawer is fully extended and then apply a steady but very firm pull.

When it comes time to reinstall the drawer you reach into the drawer opening and then pull the bearing carrier tray fully out up to the face frame. Then you carefully re-inseret the drawer with the tracks lined up. The tapered nose on the track at the back end of the drawer will engage with the bearing carrier and then you just push the drawer in. It will roll in easily until just before it becomes fully seated against the face frame. At this point you apply firm steady pressure on the drawer to push it fully in. The pressure applied in this latter step will be similar to the tug that you had to apply upon removal of the drawer.

Comment: I will be sure and give this a try this weekend! Thanks!